# PHPExcel Cells over lapping each other >setRowHeight(-1) auto cell height not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

---

### Update

> Tested using **PHPSpreadsheet** I have this code below that I have tried. It seems to work on **MSOffice Excel** if I use xls when I write the file. *Note not working with **Libre Office** does not auto resize row need it to work with libre office as well.*

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

foreach($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rowID) { 
    $rowID->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

New Controller

```
<?php

require(APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

class Events extends MX_Controller {

    public function test() {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(24);

        foreach(range('A','B') as $columnID) {
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

        foreach($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rowID) { 
            $rowID->setRowHeight(-1); 
        }

        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue("A1",'Firstname')
                ->setCellValue("B1",'Lastname');

        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Users Information');

        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        /* Here there will be some code where you create $spreadsheet */

        // redirect output to client browser
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
        $writer->save('php://output');
                
        exit;

    }
}
```

---

### Original Question

I am new to phpexcel When I download my file the cells are overlapping each other.

As you can see in image the are all bunched up when have large font size.

[image]

> Question How can I make sure the cells are not over lapping each other. I tried file in libreoffice & msoffice excel and same issue.

I have tried still no change

```
foreach(range('A','D') as $columnID) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
}
    
foreach (range('A', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}

foreach(range(1, 4) as $rowID) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($rowID)->setRowHeight(-1);
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Events extends MX_Controller {

    public function generate_excel() {

        $query = $this->db->get('event');
        $excelresults = $query->result_array();

        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
        require (APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("");

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A1", 'Event');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B1", 'Event Title');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C1", 'Event Date');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D1", 'Event Start Time');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

        foreach(range('A','D') as $columnID) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
                ->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        $headerstyle = array(
            'font'  => array(
            'size'  => 25,
            'name'  => 'Candara'
            )
        );

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray($headerstyle);


        foreach (range('A', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
        } 

        $excelrow = 2;

        foreach ($excelresults as $excelresult => $excelvalue) {

            $columnstyle = array(
                'font'  => array(
                'size'  =>25,
                'name'  => 'Candara'
                )
            );

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A' . $excelrow . ':D' . $excelrow)->applyFromArray($columnstyle);


            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("B" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_title']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("C" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_date']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D" . $excelrow, $excelvalue['event_start_time']);

            $excelrow++;
        }

        ///exit();

        $filename = 'Bowling-Events-For-' . date('Y') . '.xlsx';

        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Riwaka Bowling Club Events");

        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8"); # Important 
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename."");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        
        header("Expires: 0");
        
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the `setAutoSize()` call *after* setting all the values, i.e. after `foreach ($excelresults as $excelresult => $excelvalue) {` that `foreach`. Also, `setAutoSize()` is for *width*, not *height*, so you might still not get expected results. Use this on the rows too: `$objPHPExcell->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);`

Comment: @ishegg Thank you will try your way soon just way from main PC at the moment.

Comment: @ishegg tried it your way not working

Comment: Did you try it like [this](https://3v4l.org/3upYJ)?

Comment: Yes still not working properly.

Comment: Are you using LibreOffice?

Comment: @ishegg Yes correct

Comment: I see, there seems to be a bug in it. Try setting autowrapping: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);`

Comment: Stiil not working

Comment: I really do get fed up with this bug in Libre/OpenOffice https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62268

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried it in MSoffice same problem

Comment: So show the code where you're setting the row heights

Comment: @MarkBaker I did it like this https://3v4l.org/3upYJ from ishegg comment

Comment: Does it work correctly when the files generated by /Examples/01simple.php are loaded in MS Excel, because rows 8, 10 and 12 are autoheight in that example, and I've just tested it without any problems

Comment: @MarkBaker I will re try again with the code later I am just way from main PC atm

Comment: @MarkBaker still no change I updated question I get my data from database

Comment: So /Examples/01simple.php doesn't work; what version of MS Excel are you using?

Comment: Try `$excel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1)`

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata all ready have the -1 does not work

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi, I have stitched to using the PHPOffice/spreadsheet is there a auto height for that one?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have updated the question the `->setRowHeight(-1)` it does not make it auto row height it is the cause of it over lapping

Comment: PHPSpreadsheet has exactly the same method fr setting the row height, and if PHPExcel doesn't work correctly, then neither will PHPSpreadsheet..... what version of MS Excel are you using? If it doen't work for that version, then it needs fixing, but it certainly work for 95, 2013 and 2016

Comment: All current version both MSoffice and librieoffice

Comment: @MarkBaker I have been reading through your user guide I have found out a couple of things now. If I use xls when I write file the code works fine on msoffice I have code here https://pastebin.com/raw/9xGW6vNj but not sure how to tweak it for libre office now latest version

Answer (score 8):

please check the code below, is working for me:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

To change height of all rows to auto you can do:

```
foreach($xls->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rowID) { 
    $rowID->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

Comment: I have been reading through user guide I have found out a couple of things now. If I use xls when I write the code works fine on msoffice I have code here https://pastebin.com/raw/9xGW6vNj but not sure how to tweak it for libre office now latest version

Comment: @Ravi Chauhan Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469303/how-do-i-make-automatic-height-row-based-on-content-in-the-maatwebsite-version-3